# NPR GLSL Tutorials

Tags: glsl, npr

Anyone have a good list of tutorials on doing Non photo realistic rendering with GLSL ? I have seen books on GLSL, and books on NPR, but very few books/tutorials on doing NPR with GLSL. (I want to do it with GLSL as I want real time).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I posted my [blog article](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2011/01/toon-pixel-shader.html) about simple toon shader effect generation on images with GLSL. Maybe you will be interested.

Answer (score 2):

I am very interested in NPR too. These are some tutorials/articles I have come across:

[Tron, Volumetric Lines, and Meshless Tubes](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=61)
[Silhouette Extraction](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=54)
[Antialiased Cel Shading](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=22)
[Fast High-Quality Line Visibility](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Cole_2009_FHL/cole_2009_fhl.pdf)
[Two Fast Methods for High-Quality Line Visibility](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Cole_2010_TFM/cole_tfm_preprint.pdf)
[Stylization of Line Drawings](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/proj/sg05lines/course7-8-style.pdf)
[Blueprint Rendering and "Sketchy Drawings"](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter15.html)
[Shader-Based Wireframe Drawing](http://cgg-journal.com/2008-2/06/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [wikipedia page on cel shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel-shaded_animation) and [celshading.com](http://www.celshading.com/) have some information.